# Table without clustered indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I m trying to get an idea about indexes and began with [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx) article. It says,

> When a table is stored as a heap, individual rows are identified by
> reference to a row identifier (RID) consisting of the file number,
> data page number, and slot on the page.

I have no idea what they mean by **"file number,
data page number, and slot on the page"**

Can anyone clarify please?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but avoid using table withouth clustered index. Consider clustered index as the main mean SQL server has to manage your table properly.

Comment: This is all about the internal workings of SQL Server - fascinating, but usually not interesting to people who just want to store their data and retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a clustered table, index records store the clustered key (logical identifier) of a table record.

Say, if you use a clustered primary table like this:

```
id   name
1    Jonh
2    Alice
```

and create an index on `name`, the index will store those data:

```
name   row_pointer
Alice  2
John   1
```

If your table were a heap, the index would store physical pointers to the table:

```
name   row_pointer
Alice  <file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf, page 1234, slot 2>
John   <file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf, page 1234, slot 1>
```

(this of course looks more compact in its real binary form)

File is self-explanatory, page is the 8K block in a file, slot is the record number in the page (the record TOC is stored in the header of each page)

Comment: Is there a way to actually use that "row_pointer" in a SQL statement (similar to Oracle's `rowid`, Postgres' `ctid` or DB2's `rid_bit()`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you can select it (`%%physloc%%`) but not use in a query (efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

A heap is a collection of data pages. A page is the smallest unit of data storage in Microsoft SQL Server and contains the data in the rows.  A row can only reside in one page.

If you want lots more details on the internals of SQL Server, then perhaps read 
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Internals by Kalen Delaney. I've found her books helpful in the past.

[MSDN article: Tables and Index Data Structures Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180978%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Columns like `nvarchar(max)`, `varbinary(max)`, `ntext` and so on can span multiple pages.